# Rename folder pipeline task with azure devops YAML

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have one pipeline task like below that copy file from one machine to another machine within the same network. Now after copy, I need to rename the target machine folder name but did not find anything to do the same. Can anyone help ?

```
steps: 
- task: WindowsMachineFileCopy@2
  displayName: 'myapp'
  inputs:
    SourcePath: '$(sourcepath)'
    MachineNames: '$(servername)'
    AdminUserName: '$(name)'
    AdminPassword: '$(pwd)'
    TargetPath: '$(server)'
    CleanTargetBeforeCopy: true
    CopyFilesInParallel: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you copied your files to a target folder whose path was in `$(target)`, and you wanted to rename that folder to something whose path was in `$(newTarget)`. You could add the following after your copy (if Powershell 7 isn't on the agent you can use `powershell` instead of `pwsh`:

```yaml
- pwsh: |
    Rename-Item $(target) $(newTarget)
  displayName: Rename Target Folder
```